# Iteration & Computation Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, computation

As a very very new beginner with Python & Pandas, I am looking for your support regarding an issue.

I need to iterate over columns and find out the maximum value in the concerning rows of a dataframe and write it in a new variable for each row. The number of columns is not manageable, almost 200 columns, therefore I do not want to write each required column id manually. And most importantly that I need to start from a given column id and continue with two columns id increments till a given last columns id.

Will appreciate sample codes, see attachment too.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Perhaps you would like to show what you have already tried and have not met your expectations? Stackoverflow is here to help you, but not to do your work. You need to show you have made some steps first. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df['x']=df.max(axis=1)
```

Replace `x` with the name for your desired output column.